# Vectorizable search of text in R dataframe

Tags: r, twitter, dataframe

I have a dataframe "cities.df" that contains in one column all cities of Brazil and in the other column its respective state.

In the other dataframe "tweets.df", I have a column with tweets, that might contain some reference about a city or a state.

What I'm trying to do is to add a column to tweets.df with a "estimation" of its location, assuming that if he tweeted something about a city in the state of São Paulo, he is located in the state of São Paulo.

I'm new to R, and the only way I can think of how to implement this is with a cascaded loop over all tweets and then over all cities applying a grep function. But this does not seems like the correct way to implement it with R.

```
for tweet in tweets
    for city in cities
        grep(city, tweet)
```

I wonder if there is a more "vectorizable" way to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: take a look at `expand.grid`:  something like `sapply(expand.grid(tweets, cities), function(x, y) grep(x,y))`

Comment: It is generally expected that you will provided a MWE.  That means data and actual code you've tried: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to append a column to tweets identifying the state, based on the city mentioned in the tweet. There are several problems with this. First, the cities are not unique - that is, there can be more than one city with the same name in different states. So the city does not uniquely identify the state. Second, the cities can be identified in multiple ways. For example, there are four different São Paulo's in Brazil, which are all likely to be referenced the same way, especially in a tweet.

```
São Paulo de Olivença
São Paulo do Potengi 
São Paulo das Missões
São Paulo
```

Notwithstanding all these reservations, here is a way to append the city and state names. This code also deals with the possibility that *no* city is mentioned in the tweet.

```
library(raster)
# this generates sample data - you have this already (??)
br   <- getData(country="BR",level=2)            # Brazil shapefile, admin level 2
# muni$NAME_1 has the state names; muni$NAME_2 has the city names
muni <- br@data                                  # ~5500 municipalities in Brazil
set.seed(1)                                      # for reproduceable example
cities <- muni[sample(1:nrow(muni),90),]$NAME_2  # 90 random cities in brazil
cities <- c(cities,rep("",10))                   # last 10% have no city mentioned
tweets <- sapply(1:100,function(i) paste("#random text",cities[i],"more random text"))

# you start here
result <- do.call(rbind,lapply(tweets,function(tweet) {
  indx <- sapply(muni$NAME_2, grepl, tweet,fixed=T) # all matching cities
  indx <- min(which(indx))                          # use only first match!!
  muni[indx,c("NAME_2","NAME_1")]                   # NAME_1 contains the state
}))
tweets <- data.frame(tweets,result)
head(tweets)
#                                                        tweets    NAME_2       NAME_1
# 1462                       #random text Piau more random text      Piau Minas Gerais
# 2048                     #random text Estiva more random text    Estiva Minas Gerais
# 1474 #random text Nova Esperança do Sudoeste more random text Esperança      Paraíba
# 4997                    #random text Monções more random text   Monções    São Paulo
# 1110                      #random text Goiás more random text     Goiás        Goiás
# 4941                    #random text Jumirim more random text   Jumirim    São Paulo
tail(tweets)
#                             tweets NAME_2 NAME_1
# NA4 #random text  more random text   <NA>   <NA>
# NA5 #random text  more random text   <NA>   <NA>
# NA6 #random text  more random text   <NA>   <NA>
# NA7 #random text  more random text   <NA>   <NA>
# NA8 #random text  more random text   <NA>   <NA>
# NA9 #random text  more random text   <NA>   <NA>
```

This output illustrates another problem: `Esperança` matches even though the actual city mentioned was `Nova Esperança do Sudoeste` (which is in a different state...). I don't see a simple way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it.  Consider `cities` and `tweets` to be vectors pulled from their respective data frames.  The tweets are obviously made-up and are not even words.  I just created them by sampling letters and pasting them together.  To be updated if you add some data.

The last line will return the tweets that contain a city from the `cities` list.

```
> cities
# [1] "Belém"               "Belo Horizonte"      "Blumenau"           
# [4] "Brasília"            "Campinas"            "Curitiba"           
# [7] "Florianópolis"       "Fortaleza"           "Goiania"            
# [10] "Macáe"               "Manaus"              "Niteroi"            
# [13] "Porto Alegre"        "Recife"              "Rio de Janeiro"     
# [16] "Roraima"             "Salvador"            "Santo Andre"        
# [19] "Santos"              "São José dos Campos" "São Paulo"          
# [22] "Vitória"            
> tweets
# [1] "Niteroi rjzzfbymh wj fa elxbmyfk logeb"
# [2] "no city present in this sentence"      
# [3] "Vitória zl qxllds buoo fvclizxv zqf"   
# [4] "Rio de Janeiro n zaocj u ouo bck"      
# [5] "no city present in this sentence"      
> unlist(sapply(seq(cities), function(i){
      grep(cities[i], tweets, value = TRUE)
  }))
# [1] "Niteroi rjzzfbymh wj fa elxbmyfk logeb"
# [2] "Rio de Janeiro n zaocj u ouo bck"      
# [3] "Vitória zl qxllds buoo fvclizxv zqf"
```

Comment: @user2402105, if this or any other answer worked for you, please consider accepting it as an answer.  You also benefit from accepting an answer, not just the person who answered.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you don't need to iterate over both. grep can only take one pattern at a time, but can search for results in a vector just fine. So

```
for city in cities
    grep(city, tweets)
```

is a bit more reasonable.

Comment: hmm that's true, grep over a vector will return me the indices where the word occurred, right?

Comment: @user2402105 Indeed. See `grep("a", c("apple","lemon","banana"))`